# Tkinter "pyimage5 doesn't exist"

Tags: python, tkinter

I've looked through several similar questions, but nothing is working. I have a Tkinter program that will open a second window when pressing a button. All of the images in the first window work great, but when I open the second window, I get the folling error message when I to to make a button with images:

`_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage5" doesn't exist`

The images are defined and stored like this:

`add_icon = PhotoImage(file = 'data/add_icon.gif'), subtract_icon = PhotoImage(file = 'data/subtract_icon.gif')`

And they are called like this:

`Button(edit, image = add_icon, command = add_new_pref, relief = FLAT) .grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = NSEW) Button(edit, image = subtract_icon, command = remove_pref, relief = FLAT) .grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = NSEW)`

The images are defined after the creation of the new window. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve]. My guess is that your new window is a second instance of `Tk` instead of a `Toplevel`, but without a way to reproduce your problem we can only guess.

Comment: Change `PhotoImage(file='data/add_icon.gif')` to `PhotoImage(file="data/add_icon.gif", master=edit)`

Comment: These both work great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [TheLizzard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11106801/thelizzard) for their comment:

> Change `PhotoImage(file='data/add_icon.gif')` to `PhotoImage(file="data/add_icon.gif", master=edit)`

I guess that the "MASTER" parameter will shift the image's main instance to the specified window.